# Footer not showing after Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this code to generate a Bootstrap panel using `JSON` and it's working fine. But now I need to display a page footer after this panel. But the footer is not loading after this function. Not only footer, other HTML content is also not displaying after this jQuery function. Why and how can I solve it?

```
var valMS = [
  {
    "Subject": "Test",
    "Message": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
    "Date": "12-03-17"
  },
  {
    "Subject": "Test",
    "Message": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
    "Date": "12-03-17"
  },
  {
    "Subject": "Test",
    "Message": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
    "Date": "12-03-17"
  },
  {
    "Subject": "Test",
    "Message": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
    "Date": "12-03-17"
  }
];

 $(document).ready(function () { 
  html = '<div class="container" >';
   // var flag = 0;

    $.each(valMS, function(index, v){
        html += '<div id="events" class="container"><div class="row">';
        html += '<div class="panel panel-primary"  style="width: 20%;" >';
        html += '<div class="panel-heading">'+v["Subject"]+'</div>';
        html += '<div class="panel-body">'+v["Message"]+'</div>';
        html += '<div class="panel-footer">'+v["Date"]+'</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div></div>';
     });

     $('body').append(html);
     //$( ".container" ).after( $( "<p>Test</p>" ) );
});

</script>
```

Comment: what footer? All you have shown is javascript . We have no idea what is in the page or what css is used for it. See [mcve]

Comment: Something has errored out in your `js`.. Check you browser console..

Comment: Check your browser console.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio please check my updated question. i solved my 1st problem by closing the div tag . but i also faced the same problem when the table generate. please tell my what is the error of my table generates (updated question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing the `<div>` within the loop! Try this instead:

```
html = '<div class="container" >';
$.each(valMS, function(index, v){
    html += '<div id="events" class="container"><div class="row">';
    html += '  <div class="panel panel-primary"  style="width: 20%;" >';
    html += '    <div class="panel-heading">'+v["Subject"]+'</div>';
    html += '    <div class="panel-body">'+v["Message"]+'</div>';
    html += '    <div class="panel-footer">'+v["Date"]+'</div>';
    html += '  </div>';
    html += '</div>';
 });
html += '</div>';
$('body').append(html);
```

Comment: thank you. ur answer helped to me.
please check my updated question. what is the error of table generate function. after that function I also faced same problem. footer not showing.

Comment: ok i done as u said :) this is my new question. i thought there have some limitation to ask questions. sorry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43331403/page-content-not-showing-after-jquery-function

Answer (score 0):

ok, this way ? just working with id

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <title>test</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<style>

</style>

</head>

<body>








<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

var valMS = [
  {
    "Subject": "Test",
    "Message": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
    "Date": "12-03-17"
  },
  {
    "Subject": "Test",
    "Message": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
    "Date": "12-03-17"
  },
  {
    "Subject": "Test",
    "Message": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
    "Date": "12-03-17"
  },
  {
    "Subject": "Test",
    "Message": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
    "Date": "12-03-17"
  }
];

 $(document).ready(function () { 
  html = '<div class="container" id="mypanel">';
   // var flag = 0;

    $.each(valMS, function(index, v){
        html += '<div id="events" class="container"><div class="row">';
        html += '<div class="panel panel-primary"  style="width: 20%;" >';
        html += '<div class="panel-heading">'+v["Subject"]+'</div>';
        html += '<div class="panel-body">'+v["Message"]+'</div>';
        html += '<div class="panel-footer">'+v["Date"]+'</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div></div>';
     });

     $('body').append(html);
     $( "#mypanel" ).after( $( '<div class="footer"><div class="container"<p>This is a footer</p></div></div>' ) );
});

</script>



</body>

</html>
```